# Changing CMD+1,CMD+2,... shortcuts to ALT+1,ALT+2

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

Style shortcuts are mapped to keys like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> which conflicts with MacOS spaces switching. Can someone suggest how to remap them to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>/etc.?

Keyboard translations file for Mac is in 
`/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh/KeyEventTranslations.tr`

However, `Alt+1` and `Alt+Shift+1` are already captured by macos, and I couldn't get `Cmd+Shift+1` mapped to anything (something else captures it?), it turned out easier to change MacOS shortcuts (System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts) to free up `Cmd+1` rather than changing Mathematica defaults

Comment: I use OSX as well, and my suggestion worked for me. You need to restart Mathematica to see the changes though. Perhaps you didn't do that?

Comment: do I need to evaluate the `SetOptions` command every time I start mathematica?

Comment: You just need to use a stylesheet where you assign MenuCommandKey->None to relevant styles, and then save the notebook with that stylesheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eliminate the style key bindings by setting `MenuCommandKey->None` for the existing styles. For example, if you evaluate:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions->Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Title"],MenuCommandKey->None],
        Cell[StyleData["Chapter"],MenuCommandKey->None]
        },
        WindowSize->{808,689},
        WindowMargins->{{38,Automatic},{-80,Automatic}},
        Visible->False,
        FrontEndVersion->"11.1 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (January 4, 2017)",
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

the bindings for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> should be gone. You can also use `MenuCommandKey->key` to change to a different <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+`key` combination, but care must be taken to avoid conflicts with key bindings defined in the menu system.

If you want to change the binding to something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, you could edit `KeyEventTranslations.tr`. An example of a key binding that can be added:

```
    Item[KeyEvent["1", Modifiers -> {Option}], "Style" -> "Title"]
```

I believe the precedence for key bindings is:

```
MenuSetup.tr > KeyEventTranslations.tr > Operating System
```

Comment: Can you give some hints on what specifically to add to `KeyEventTranslations.tr` for this?

Comment: @Szabolcs I added an example.

Comment: so, in the end "Alt+1" and "Shift+Alt+1" are getting intercepted by Mac to make funny characters, and "Shift+Cmd+1" is intercepted by something (I can't map anything to it through `KeyEventTranslations.tr`), the simplest thing in the end ended up being to change my MacOS bindings for switching spaces and keep Mathematica defaults